# Excel Line Graph - Putting 2 rdifferent Variables on X Axis from table

Tags: excel, graph, axis, axis-labels

I'm having trouble putting data on 2 different types of data on my x-axis from the data in my table. How can I get the month and year data from my table to a line graph like this?

[image]

Like in the graph shown, I want all to group the x-axis by year range (2001-2002, 2002-2003, etc). And then within each year range, I want the values for each month to show for that year from August to May. And repeat this again for each year interval.

What should I select on select data source to make it look like the graph shown?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, you can arrange your data this way (I've only included 3 years):

[image]

Every cell that seems blank is really blank, that is, it doesn't contain a formula or a space or anything that doesn't appear. The "XXX" in the second cell of the second column is temporary. Create your line chart with this data, then delete the "XXX" and format the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend combining the month and year dimensions into a single month-year column and making the values line up in a single column. Then put month-year on the x axis and values on the y axis.